# Select row if first selection mach, if not, move to next selection

Tags: mysql

I have 1 table with name and language columns.

Let's say I have 2 languages available with id 1 and 2
I want to select all the name with language = 2, if any row is not available in language = 2, then I will select the one with language 1. Only get the row with language = 1 if language = 2 not available

```
ID language name(as code)
1  1        name_1
2  2        name_1
3  1        name_2
```

I want to get something like this:

```
ID language name
1  2        name_1
3  1        name_2
```

Thanks for your help. Sorry for my English

Comment: how do you define selection?

Comment: please, put some sample

Comment: How do you know if two rows are in fact the same name in different languages?

Comment: I have added an example, Hope it will clear my idea to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want all rows of language 1 (defaults) with values of language 2 (only if I exists), so:

The table:

```
create table `lang`
(
    id int,
    lang_id int,
    name varchar(20),
    description varchar(255)
);
```

Some data:

```
insert into `lang` (id, lang_id, name, description) values
(1, 1, 'language', 'English'),
(2, 2, 'language', 'Português'),
(3, 1, 'title', 'My Project'),
(4, 2, 'title', 'Meu Projeto'),
(5, 1, 'var1', 'My English only variable');
```

The query:

```
select 

c1.name, coalesce(c2.description, c1.description) as description

from lang c1

left join lang c2 on c1.name = c2.name and c2.lang_id = 2

where c1.lang_id = 1
```

The result:

> ```
> name     | description
> language | Português
> title    | Meu Projeto
> var1     | My English only variable
> ```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce4608/2/0)**

Answer (score 0):

you car write your query like this:

```
SELECT ......
FROM mytable
WHERE ........ (without languageID)
ORDER BY languageID DESC (if you want to have 2 else ASC)
LIMIT 1;
```

so it will only select laguageID 2 if exist else 1 or 0

**one Sample more**

```
SELECT ......
FROM mytable
WHERE ........ (without languageID)
ORDER BY ELT(languageID,'1','0','4','3');
```

the numbers IN elt are the order ID. lets say you want TO have LANGUAGEid  2 AS FIRST put the lowest NO IN field 2 LIKE 0

Comment: Thanks, But I want to get a collection, not single row

Answer (score 0):

your answer is like this.

```
select *
from   t
where  language = 2
union
select *
from   t
where  language = 1 
       and 0 in (select count(1) 
                 from   t
                 where  language = 2)
```

the first select get all name with language = 2

the second select get all name with language = 1 if there is not any name with language = 2